# Synonymize the tag [colab] with the main tag [google-colaboratory]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I propose to add the tag synonym [google-colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-colaboratory) ← [colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colab)

- `google-colaboratory` has 4,151 questions, a tag wiki and usage guidance
- `colab` has 141 questions, no tag wiki and no usage guidance
- There's an overlap of 79 questions tagged with both tags `google-colaboratory` and `colab`
- Searching for [`[colab] -[google-colaboratory] is:q -"google colab"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcolab%5D+-%5Bgoogle-colaboratory%5D+is%3Aq+-%22google+colab%22) only nets 27 leftover questions that all are about Google Colaboratory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks; good suggestion! After reviewing the current status, I confirmed that this was an obviously appropriate merge, so I've gone ahead and pulled the trigger.

For now, I've left the synonym in place mapping [google-colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-colaboratory) ← [colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colab), but this may need to be revisited if "colab" is too generic of a term (being a relatively common contraction of "collaboration" in a variety of contexts).